# Giving each glossary definition a paragraph number

Tags: sectioning, glossaries

Using the `glossaries` package, how can I convince LaTeX to print and increment the `paragraph` number every time it prints out a definition?

I've tried e.g.

```
\newglossaryentry{word}{name={...}, description={ \paragraph{} ... }}
```

But this vomits an opaque error: `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`

M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{thewerd}{name={thewerd}, description={ \paragraph{} }}
\begin{document}
\gls{thewerd}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `list` style uses `description` and you can't include sectioning commands within a list environment. I think the simplest method is to use one of the tree-like styles and redefine `\glstreepredesc`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=index]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{thewerd}{name={thewerd}, description={example 
description}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\renewcommand{\glstreepredesc}{\paragraph{}}

\begin{document}
\gls{thewerd}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would one link this to the `paragraph` counter?

Comment: @user Sorry, I misread your question. I've changed my answer.